# Typescript create type from string array and object

Tags: typescript

I have this static array that may grow over time. Eg maybe in a month I will add another entry.

```
const GROUPS = ['Objects', 'Things', 'Stuff']
```

All of these refer to an interface, such as

```
interface Group { name: string, level: number}
```

How do I make a TS type that maps it with only the allowed const strings?

```
type GroupType = {[key: GROUPS]: Group}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, in order for the compiler to keep track of the [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) of the elements of `GROUPS` and not just `string`, you should use a [`const` assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) when you initialize it:

```
const GROUPS = ['Objects', 'Things', 'Stuff'] as const;
// const GROUPS: readonly ["Objects", "Things", "Stuff"]
```

You can see that `GROUPS`'s type is now a [`readonly` tuple](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#readonly-tuple-types) consisting of literal types.

Once you do that you can define `GroupType` as a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of elements of the `GROUPS` array, by [indexing into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the type `typeof GROUPS` (using [the `typeof` type operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html)) with a `number` index (since the type you get when accessing `GROUPS[n]` where `n` is of type `number` is a union of the element types):

```
type GroupType = { [K in typeof GROUPS[number]]: Group }
/* type GroupType = {
    Objects: Group;
    Things: Group;
    Stuff: Group;
} */
```

You could also write this out like:

```
type GROUPS = typeof GROUPS[number];
type GroupType = Record<GROUPS, Group>;
/* type GroupType = {
    Objects: Group;
    Things: Group;
    Stuff: Group;
} */
```

where we give a *type* named `GROUPS` to the element types of the `GROUPS` *value*, and we use [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) instead of the equivalent manually-written mapped type.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.8.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBA4gJQPIFUAKBlGBeGBtAciQCMArAU2CggIBoYCAVACwEswBzG+gjKAVwBmgggF0YAQwgxQkKAG4AUAHplM8NHjJ0GAFwwATuQkATcABsAnvgBEJClQg36Nluy7OYNvkME3RiorsUOQGghLA5PAGIPwADjAA3jBgEgC25PrQBu705uQAbuTm+mD8acShMAC+gVCWcVFwMfGMDVG4yXgA0jDsMPWNIIJaqJh4ZRWhoqL6zbEJtcoAVAPt0QttjThJijD7MPaU1HMtcUoHMG6cEKcLFwc+wnfxStUwy8qBioNN2pg7X7DUY6CblSoGURKX4bVrtABMOwQlBABhMAB5EGMMPR5vEAHxKFZrbZ4uJbciIzp7A5HRwvc40-bXLgMh77J6CNmKd6fIA)

Comment: Does this work if I already have an array defined? ie `const GROUPKEYS = [...GROUPS] as const`.. Doesn't seem to work. I mean, it compiles, but does not show the keys.

Comment: No. `as const` tells the compiler to preserve some of the information it would have otherwise thrown away.  By the time you write `[...GROUPS] as const` apparently `GROUPS` has already been created and the info you need thrown away.  `as const` doesn't resurrect dead information.